# List all SVN repository URLs from a folder in recursive mode

Tags: linux, svn, bash, shell

We are looking for a script that will traverse in recursive mode all subfolders and list all SVN repository URLs and the path where it was found.

It will be used on /home folder of a user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursively find directories, and for each of them try to get the SVN info. If it is successfull, then don't descend into the directory and print the directory name.

```
find -type d -exec bash -c "svn info {} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null" \; -prune -print
```

This will list the directories.

If you want the repository info, you can add it in the middle of the find exec command.

```
find -type d -exec bash -c "svn info {} 2> /dev/null | grep URL" \; -prune -print
```

**Edit:**

I found much better results by only testing for the presence of an `.svn` subdirectory. Then, `svn info` is called once at the end and grepped for Path and URL. (Plus using -0 to prevent from spaces in filenames.)

```
find -type d -exec test -d "{}/.svn" \; -prune -print0 | xargs -0 svn info | grep -e '\(Path\|URL\)'
```

Comment: How do you read the URL? I cannot locate  `svn info | grep URL` in your script?

Comment: This will print the directories. If you want the URL, then call `svn info` on each of them.

Comment: I want the folder and the URL together. But the url is the most important.

Comment: This starts to work. What does that `svn info {} 2` mean? what's that {} and what 2 means here?

Comment: Still only getting ".", except for the last one which prints nothing but returns error 123. Clearly have a different set up, but it would be useful to know what's causing it not to work.

Comment: @Thor84no I can confirm this works on SVN1.6 with slight errors.

Comment: I get some chatter probably with folders where we have spaces or special characters https://gist.github.com/1347855

Comment: @Pentium10 I'm using version 1.6.12 so it's not that. (Bash version 4.2.8).

Comment: @DidierTrosset if the repository path is long, I get cut off.

Comment: @DidierTrosset with the latest update, I lose I think the recursive mode, as I get only 4 hits instead of 21 (the previous one does).

Comment: @Pentium10 `find` is always recursive. The thing is that as soon as it finds a directory that has a `.svn` subdir, it does not descend into it (`-prune`). But it was already the case with the previous versions that were running `svn info` within `find`. I'm a bit surprised at this point, I've to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of limitations you have there could be different ways. The easiest way would be to do `svn ls -R | grep -v "\."` to grab all the sub-folders from the repository location you're at and feed that in to a `for` loop that adds the URI to the root of the ls to the front of each line. This will however not be adequate if you have files that do not contain a "." as they will be detected as folders. Unfortunately `svn ls` doesn't allow you to filter by file/folder, so if you need to deal with filenames without extensions then you'd have to do something different such as checking out the source and using find to get the folder names.

Comment: The current folder I am in, is not a SVN repository, but it might have in one of their descendants

Answer (score 0):

```
user_home=... # fill in the user's home dir
old_dir=/../
find $user_home -name .svn | rev | cut -f2- -d/ | rev | while read line ; do
    echo -n "$line"$'\t'
    wc -c <<<"$line"
done | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2n | while read dir size ; do
    if [[ $dir != $old_dir* ]] ; then
        old_dir=$dir
        svn info $dir | grep URL
        echo PATH: $dir
        echo
    fi
done
```

Just hope users do not store SVN under directories with spaces in names.